# JMeter 'Problem with SSL certificate' after installing root certificate

Tags: ssl, jmeter, certificate

Currently trying to see what https calls are made by a thick client application using JMeter HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder. However for some calls I am getting "Problem with SSL certificate for url  for '...'? Ensure browser..."

The Apache Generated Certificate has been installed on the JRE used by the application as well as the keystores that are used by the application. This allowed us to begin recording and get some calls, however for one domain we do not get anything.

When the JMeter cert is installed on IE, we can access the domain without SSL error. Note that we *do* get an SSL error when trying to access without the proxy server - Is this related?

Bit stuck here unfortunately, I've been looking into a way we can use group policy to force the certificate to be used? Is this a good approach? (+ Would it even work?)

Comment: To add onto this, the domain it is trying to access is self-signed. Could this be related? e.g. Able to intercept traffic to https://google.com, but not to https://redacted.corp:10443/blah/

Comment: Ended up using the self-signed crt/key used by the application to intercept traffic using mitmproxy